# PushButton handler does noch work after disable -> enable in GWT

Tags: java, events, gwt, button, handler

I disable a button and enable this button with a timer (like this sample), i dont move the mouse pointer down from the button. the result is, the button is enabled, but some times i can't click on it or it does not fire a event.

Edit: it works with the default button, not with the PushButton

```
        btntest.addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick( ClickEvent event ) {
            btntest.setEnabled( false );
            Timer t = new Timer() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btntest.setEnabled( true );
                }
            };
            t.schedule( 1000 );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: 99% sure this is a browser bug. Try the same in pure JS to confirm (provided you used a Button, and not a CustomButton)

Answer (score 0):

Try to setEnable(false) within a Scheduler#scheduleDeferred rather than from within the ClickHandler directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug, but there is a workaround. Both described at https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8657